# How do I "preventDefault" for custom events

Tags: javascript

The following code is a simplified version of a module I am making where I want to implement custom "beforeopen" and "beforeclose" events. I want to be able to listen to these events, and cancel the open or close methods from continuing from inside the eventlistener function. For standard events, you can just do e.preventDefault() to cancel the default behavior assosiated with the event. This of course does not work for my custom event, but I want to know how I can make it work. Can I tell my event what the default action assosiated with the event is anyhow? Or are there other workarounds to make this work.

```js
const element = document.querySelector(".element");
const openButton = document.querySelector(".openButton");

function open() {
  element.dispatchEvent(new Event("beforeopen"));
  // if default is prevented, I want to stop the function from continuing!
  element.setAttribute("data-open", "");
}

element.addEventListener("beforeopen", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
});

openButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  open();
});
```

```css
.element {
  display: none;
}
.element[data-open] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">Element opened - Failed to prevent default</div>

<button class="openButton">Open</button>
```

Comment: Im sorry but stackoverflow shows "How can I remove an item from an array", and similar as the related questions. I did not know it had been asked on here before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`cancelable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event#cancelable) flag of your new `Event` object, afterward, you can call `preventDefault()` on it and check its `defaultPrevented` attribute.

```js
const element = document.querySelector(".element");
const openButton = document.querySelector(".openButton");

function open() {
  const evt = new Event("beforeopen", { cancelable: true });
  element.dispatchEvent(evt);
  if (evt.defaultPrevented) {
    console.log("prevented");
    return;
  }
  // if default is prevented, I want to stop the function from continuing!
  element.setAttribute("data-open", "");
}

element.addEventListener("beforeopen", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
});

openButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  open();
});
```

```css
.element {
  display: none;
}
.element[data-open] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">Element opened - Failed to prevent default</div>

<button class="openButton">Open</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```js
function open() {
  const ev = new Event('beforeopen');
  element.dispatchEvent(ev);
  if (ev.defaultPrevented) return;
  element.setAttribute("data-open", "");
}
```